Property cannot be assigned to
        local Core = Instance.new("Part",workspace)
        local OuterCore = Instance.new("Part",workspace)
        Core.CanCollide = false
        OuterCore.CanCollide = false
        Core.Position = Missile.Position
        OuterCore = Core.Position
        Core.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("New Yeller")
        OuterCore.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Neon orange")
        Core.Transparency = 0.3
        OuterCore.Transparency = 0.3 

Literally no property can be assigned to the part except for parent. The error is "(property) cannot be assigned to".This is inside a module script if that helps. Please help

the problem is in this line:
OuterCore = Core.Position

this line will set the variable OuterCore to a Vector3 value and BrickColor is not a valid member of Vector3 resulting into this error: BrickColor cannot be assigned to.
the way to fix this error is to change that line to the following:
OuterCore.Position = Core.Position


The error you're getting is : BrickColor cannot be assigned to
This tells you that you cannot set the BrickColor property, which is surprising because even the documentation outright tells you to do it this way.
-- By color name
workspace.Part.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Pastel Blue")

-- By numerical index
workspace.Part.BrickColor = BrickColor.new(11)

-- By RGB decimal values in range of 0-1
workspace.Part.BrickColor = BrickColor.new(0.502, 0.734, 0.859)

So the workaround is to update your code to set the Color property instead.
        Core.Color = BrickColor.new("New Yeller").Color
        OuterCore.Color = BrickColor.new("Neon orange").Color

